# redirect SCP output to file

Tags: redirect, scp, io-redirection

I've tried:

```
scp -r file host:~/ 2>&1 | tee -a file.log
scp -r file host:~/ >file.log 2>&1
scp -r file host:~/ &>file.log
```

and i only ever get a blank file.
what am I doing wrong?
the goal is to capture the output of the files transferred to the text file

Comment: No clue why this was downvoted. It's a perfect question. Take my +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `script`:

```
script -q -c "scp -r file host:~/" > file.log
```

Comment: @KaanSoral - so `scp` on macos needs an extra `-c`?  There's already one as an argument to `script`.

Comment: no, `-c` simply doesn't exist for the `script` command on macos, otherwise your solution would be perfect - I looked around for a more unix-like `script` command for macos but came up empty

Comment: You might get some joy with `osascript -e`

Comment: file.log literally just says "user@host's password:" and I never get prompted for the  password on the actual  command window.

Comment: @user1271772 - I think because `-c` is running the command rather than an interactive shell you can't interact with it. So you need to do passwordless access to the host, likely with a SSH key.

Comment: @IBam: This particular host does not let us do password-less access :'(