# redirect screen output to file

Tags: bash, file, output, screen, scp

I'm trying to redirect the screen output to a log file but I don't seem to be getting this right, see the code below:

```
DT=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%m-%s)
echo $DT > log_copy_$DT.txt

cat dirfiles.txt | while read f ; do
dest=/mydir
scp "${f}" $dest >> log_copy_$DT.txt 2>&1
done
```

All I get is a file with the date, but not the screen results (I need to see if the files copied correctly).

So, basically I'm appending the results of the scp command into the log and doing the 2>&1 so that the standard output screen is written to the file but doesn't seem to work.

I need to run this on a crontab so I'm not sure if the screen contents will even go to the log once I set it up.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: It helps but I can't see why it is not sending the screen output to the file

Comment: See: [redirect SCP output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32637393/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after investigating, it seems scp can't really write standard screen output to a file, it kinda cancels the standard out as it shows % progress, so I ended up doing this:

```
scp "${f}" $dest && echo $f successfully copied! >> log_copy_$DT.txt
```

basically, it it can copy the file over, then it writes a message saying it was OK.